# Pointers to elements of STL containers

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, memory-address

Given an STL container (you may also take `boost::unordered_map` and `boost::multi_index_container` into account) that is non-contiguous, is it guaranteed that the memory addresses of the elements inside the container never changes if no element is removed, (but new ones can be added)?

e.g.

```
class ABC { };
//
//...
//
std::list<ABC> abclist;
ABC abc;
abclist.insert(abc);
ABC * abc_ptr = &(*abclist.begin());
```

In other word will `abc_ptr` be pointed to `abc` throughout the execution, if I do not remove `abc` from `abc_list`.

I am asking this because I am going to wrap the class `ABC` in C++/Cli, so I need pointers to the `ABC` instances in the wrapper class. ABC is a simple class and I want the container to handle the memory. If the answer is no then I will use `std::list<ABC*>`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`std::list`, `std::set`, and `std::map` guarantee that the iterators (including simple pointers) will not be invalidated when a new element is added or even removed.

Comment: OP specified a non-contiguous container, so vector is out of the running. Also, was something supposed to come after "See"?

Comment: And `deque` guarantees it for adding elements at the ends, which might be good enough for this sort of use.

Answer (score 5):

The C++ Standard places stringent rules on the validity of references / iterators. For each container, each method documents which elements *may* be moved (invalidating references and iterators).

The Node Based Containers: `list`, `map`, `set`, `multimap` and `multiset` guarantee that references and iterators to elements will remain valid as long as the element is not removed from the container.

Your use case is therefore one of the corner cases where using a `list` for storage is good, because of the invalidation guarantees that list offer.

Answer (score 5):

As Armen mentioned std::list, std::set, and std::map are guaranteed to only invalidate the removed iterator. In the case of boost::unodered_map, the modifiers may indeed invalidate iterators.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes according to documentation, the modifiers may indeed invalidate iterators, also it says `Pointers and references to elements are never invalidated.` which I need to know. Also `boost::multi_index::hashed_unique` index is implemented like `boost::unordered_map`.