# Extending a thrift generated object in C++

Tags: c++, thrift

Using the following `.thrift` file

```
struct myElement {
  1: required i32 num,
}

struct stuff {
  1: optional map<i32,myElement> mymap,
}
```

I get thrift-generated class with an STL map.  The instance of this class is long-lived
(I append and remove from it as well as write it to disk using TSimpleFileTransport).

I would like to extend `myElement` in C++, the extenstions should not affect 
the serialized version of this object (and this object is not used in any 
other language).  Whats a clean way to acomplish that?

I contemplated the following, but they didn't seem clean:

1. Make a second, non thrift map that is indexed with the same key

   - keeping both in sync could prove to be a pain
2. Modify the generated code either by post-processing of the generated 
   header (incl. proprocessor hackery).
3. Similar to #2, but modify the generation side to include the following in the generated struct and then define NAME_CXX_EXT in a forced-included header

   > ```
   >   #ifdef NAME_CXX_EXT
   >   NAME_CXX_EXT ...
   >   #endif
   > ```

All of the above seem rather nasty

---

**The solution I am going to go with for now:**

[This is all pseudo code, didn't check this copy for compilation]

The following generated code, which I cannot modify
(though I can change the map to a set)

```
class GeneratedElement {
 public:
   // ...
   int32_t num;
   // ...
};


class GeneratedMap {
 public:
   // ...
   std::map<int32_t, GeneratedElement>  myGeneratedMap;
   // ...
};

// End of generated code
```

Elsewhere in the app:

```
class Element {
 public:
   GeneratedElement* pGenerated; // <<== ptr into element of another std::map!
   time_t lastAccessTime;
};


class MapWrapper {
private:
  GeneratedMap theGenerated; 

 public:
   // ...
   std::map<int32_t, Element>  myMap;
   // ...

   void doStuffWIthBoth(int32_t key)
   {
     // instead of 
     //   theGenerated.myGeneratedMap[key].num++;  [lookup in map #1]
     //   time(&myMap[key].lastAccessTime);        [lookup in map #2]
     Element& el=myMap[key];
     el.pGenerated->num++;
     time(&el.lastAccessTime);
   }
};
```

I wanted to avoid the double map lookup for every access 
(though I know that the complexity remains the same, it is still two lookups ).

I figured I can guarantee that all insertions and removals to/from the `theGenerated`) 
are done in a single spot, and in that same spot is where I populate/remove
the corresponding entry in `myMap`, I would then be able to initialize
Element::pGenerated to its corresponding element in theGenerated.myGeneratedMap

Not only will this let me save half of the lookup time, I may even change 
myMap to a better container type for my keytype (say a hash_map or even a boost 
multi index map)

At first this sounded to me like a bad idea.  With std::vector and std::dqueue I can 
see how this can be a problem as the values will be moved around, 
invalidating the pointers.  Given that std::map is implemented with a tree 
structure, is there really a time where a map element will be relocated?
(my above assumptions were confirmed by the discussion in [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182122/pointers-to-elements-of-stl-containers))

While I probably won't provide an access method to each member of `myElement` or any syntactic sugar (like overloading [] () etc), this lets me treat these elements almost a consistent manner.  The only key is that (aside for insertion) I never look for members of `mymap` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just using simple containership?

You're using C++, so you can just wrap the struct(s) in some class or other struct, and provide wrapper methods to do whatever you want.

Comment: if I understand you correctly you propose that I wrap `stuff` in another class.  If so how is it going to help me with extending `myElement`s?  If this is not what you meant - then I think I need an example.  At the end it seems like lots of access methods to develop with primary benefit being syntactic (sugar) to the external user